# Attribute theme is also present

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Since i updated buildSdkVersion to 33, when i try to bundleRelease my app (react-native) i have the following errors:

```
Attribute activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity@theme value=(@android:style/Theme) from [com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.0] AndroidManifest.xml:41:13-49
        is also present at [androidx.test:core:1.5.0] AndroidManifest.xml:30:13-56 value=(@style/WhiteBackgroundTheme).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml:38:9-45:20 to override.
```

3 errors of this type, all involving [androidx.test:core:1.5.0]

i tried to add the following suggestion to my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml:38:9-45:20 to override.
```

but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue. The errors seems to find itself in the app/build generated folder.

[Error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/durTu.png)